# copy down values using partition or any other functions in impala

Tags: sql, oracle, impala

wanted to copy down values in impala or sql using partition or any other functions.

Input table
[image]

resultant table

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "copy down". At least in Oracle, data is not ordered within a table. Your SQL update command would have to base the value of col3 on something *other* than row placement.

Comment: Please, show your current attempt and describe what was wrong with it. Why you tagged Oracle and Impala? What do you mean by `update`?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, use the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       LAST_VALUE(col3) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2)
         AS col3
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(col1, col2, col3) AS
SELECT 'AA', DATE '2021-01-26', 'BB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA', DATE '2021-01-27', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA', DATE '2021-01-28', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA', DATE '2021-01-29', 'CC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA', DATE '2021-01-30', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA', DATE '2021-01-31', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA', DATE '2021-02-01', 'BA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA', DATE '2021-02-02', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA', DATE '2021-02-03', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | AA | 26-JAN-21 | BB |
> | AA | 27-JAN-21 | BB |
> | AA | 28-JAN-21 | BB |
> | AA | 29-JAN-21 | CC |
> | AA | 30-JAN-21 | CC |
> | AA | 31-JAN-21 | CC |
> | AA | 01-FEB-21 | BA |
> | AA | 02-FEB-21 | BA |
> | AA | 03-FEB-21 | BA |

If you want to update the table then you can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         LAST_VALUE(col3) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2)
           AS col3
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET col3 = src.col3;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3cbfda7bae8898cb45e3c35997a3f2a8)*

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
with cte as
(select *,row_number()over(partition by col3 order by col2) as rn1,
row_number()over( order by col2) as rn2 ,
lag(col3) over(order by col2) as v from a
) select col1,col2,
 max(coalesce(col3,v)) over(partition by rn2-rn1) as col3  from cte order by col2
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7e88e20544d2a05e0fa6c19b03af164)

[image]